# SSL Packet inspection on Linux

Tags: linux, ssl, https, wireshark, packet-capture

I'm trying to build a web client for an HTTPS website. I think I've done everything right, yet obviously I get a different result in the browser than with my crawler.

As far as I understand, there is no way to examine an SSL packet. But, I'm not sure I'm right on this so I'm looking for verification. Presumably SSL traffic goes through some SSL-specific library (openssl) and not everyone re-invents this wheel. Is here anyway I can get wireshark or something to work with it to intercept traffic so I can compare the headers of my client, and Firefox.

Answer (score 9):

Wireshark can decrypt SSL if you have the RSA key for the certificate used by the server.  Instructions can be found [here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL).